# windows azure in Xp

Tags: windows, azure

Is there any way to Install and program windows azure in Windows XP operating system?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Azure SDK requires **Windows Vista or higher**.

Technically you can run **Win 7 in Virtual Machine in Windows XP**, installing and using SDK inside. However it'll be **simpler just to upgrade OS**.

Answer (score 1):

Rinat's correct. To be more specific: The Dev Fabric requires IIS 7, which is available on Vista and Windows 7. Technically, you could install the SDK and build an Azure application on XP, but you'd have no ability to test in the Dev Fabric, which would be a big penalty. As an Azure developer, you'll find that you can do the vast majority of your testing in the Dev Fabric without having to constantly push new builds to Azure (which would add about 10-15 minutes every time you need to deploy).